# Aggregating data from a RESTful API

Tags: php, python

I am on a mission to understand how to pull data from a RESTful API, parse it, store it in a database in iterations and make the most recent parsed data available for retrieval on a website.

Problem is, I have no earthly idea how to do it!

If someone could provide some simple example codes and tie it all together that would be much appreciated. The most important thing to me is understand how to grab data, how to parse it, then how to display that on a website and grab data based on what users want.

I have an example project that you can look at (https://github.com/fuzzysteve/FuzzMarket) <-- This is essentially what I am trying to accomplish. I understand how the author uses twig framework for php for template. What I don't understand is everything else.

Who does php actually interact with and obtain the data for display?
How is the data parsed and stored?
What server-side applications is he using? So far I have identified twig, but I am at a loss for what else is being used besides a web server, some form of database, php and python.

Thanks,
XeroCo

Comment: In the repo you linked, there are some python files in `scripts/` that the person uses to pull data from the eve api at `https://esi.tech.ccp.is`, massage it a little, and then store it in a postgresql database. Those are probably hooked up to a cron task. To serve it back, a simple webapp written in [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) is being served from `public/index.php`. This webapp reads the data out of their postgresql database and displays it back in whatever form they liked.

Comment: Okay, so how did you work that out?
I see that the scripts are aggregating the data, but I don't think the author provided everything required to see exactly what is happening (or I am not seeing it)

Cron and posgre makes sense

"Simple" haha. His code makes sense, I like how he uses twig and slim to create a template-based site. What I don't understand is how this is configured server-side. For example when you go to http://website.com/about/  how does the server know to load index.php, then load base.phtml, then extend it using about.phtml?

I am tremendously confused!

Comment: [slim has docs for how to serve it with different servers](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html). The http server should send all requests directly to `public/index.php`, and slim will decide which action a url gets mapped to with its [`Router`](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html). In your linked repo, those actions are in `https://github.com/fuzzysteve/FuzzMarket/blob/master/src/routes.php`, those different actions pull data, organize some, then pass it to a template via `$this->renderer->render($response, 'appraisal.phtml', $args)`.